# Unity emitting Json string when ever using best http2 plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, socket.io

I am using best http2 as a plugin in unity for socket IO but when i am emit data to server in server side it show i am sending string but in my side i added `JsonUtility.tojson` then why it send data as a string.

i tried using new jsonObject but it shows me a big error.

Comment: I don't fully understand what your question is, but when you send something over http is will be a string (in json representation). You have to serialize your data to json and then you have to deserialize when you receive it. Maybe 'JsonUtility.FromJson' could help you.

Comment: Json is a string.. its just a known format of string